# c# If else if statement event triggers before else if does

Tags: c#, button, if-statement

so I have hidden buttons, that I only want to show when maxAttempts has been reached, with the code below, the buttons open after the first wrong attempt. Also while I'm at it, I want to disable a button and a textbox at game over, but when I write btncheckAnswer.disable and txtResult.disable I see exceptions.

Any suggestions?

```
 private void btnCheckAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var userAnswer = double.Parse(txtResult.Text);
        if (!puzzle.CheckTheAnswer(userAnswer))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong");
            numAttempts++;
            if (numAttempts < maxAttempts)
            {  // UpdateImage();
                NextQuestion();
            }
            else
                if (numAttempts == maxAttempts)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Game Over");
                    btnClose.Show();
                    btnNewGame.Show();
                    //btnCheckAnswer.disable();
                    //txtResult.disable;()
                    //Stop the game ();
                    //Block text box from receiving data

                    return;
                }

        }

        else MessageBox.Show("Smarty Pants, You're Right!!");
        {
            NextQuestion();
        }
        return;
```

Comment: What is the value of `maxAttempts` when that happens (don't guess, be sure)? What is the initial value of `numAttempts` (ditto)? What does `NextQuestion()` do - does it modify either value?

Comment: `If else if statement event triggers before else if does`  a) There is no such thing b) They are not events.....

Comment: @PaulRoub maxAttempts is 5, numAttempts is global starting at zero, each wrong answer increments one up to give when game should end. NextQuestion(); clears txtResult and plugs in another question. How do I format the if else if else correctly?

Comment: See Joe Enos's answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This only addresses the second portion of the question.

To disable a control try setting enabled to false.

```
btnCheckAnswer.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: And you think this is the problem? Read the question again.

Comment: @sean J. Thank you for this advice it's what I needed.

Comment: @EZI OP asked two questions, " Also while I'm at it, I want to disable a button ... ". Benj851, in future please keep it to one question per question, to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Your "Smarty Pants" line needs to be inside the curly brackets.

```
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Smarty Pants, You're Right!!");
    NextQuestion();
}
```

As it stands, that's the only line in your "else" clause, which means `NextQuestion()` will always fire.

Answer (score 1):

To add slightly to @Joe's answer (this would be a comment except it needs formatting), this is what that `else` section of code looks like, formatted correctly:

```
else 
    MessageBox.Show("Smarty Pants, You're Right!!");

{
    NextQuestion();
}
```

Notice that the `{}` block isn't attached to an `if`, it's just a block on its own.

Comment: Thank you. I have many more like that. I'm new to programming. I appreciate your assistance.